# php-mysql insert into "table" No me muestra ningun error, tampoco me registra los datos en la tabla

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

#### PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
require("funciones.php");
    $error="";
    if (array_key_exists("Logout", $_GET))
    {
        //Proviene de mi-oficina.php
        session_unset();
        setcookie("CodUFree","",time()-60*60);
        $_COOKIE['CodUFree']="";
    }
    else if ((array_key_exists("CodUFree",$_SESSION) AND $_SESSION['CodUFree']) OR (array_key_exists("CodUFree", $_COOKIE) AND $_COOKIE['CodUFree']))
    {
        header("Location: mi-oficina.php");
    }
    if (array_key_exists("submit", $_POST))
    {
        if (!$_POST['nombre'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Debes ingresar tu nombre.";
        }
        if (!$_POST['apellido'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Debes ingresar tu nombre.";
        }
        if (!$_POST['email'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Debes ingresar un email.";
        }
        if (!$_POST['password'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Debes ingresar una contraseña .";
        }
        if (!$_POST['telefono'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Debes ingresar un número de telefono.";
        }
        if (!$_POST['profesion'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Debes indicar a que te dedicas";
        }
        if (!$_POST['ciudad'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Ingresa la ciudad donde vives";
        }
        if (!$_POST['estado'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Ingresa la Provincia o Estado donde te encuentras";
        }
        if (!$_POST['zip'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Debes ingresar tu código postal";
        }
        if (!$_POST['direccion'])
        {
            $error .="<br>Debes ingresar una dirección.";
        }
        if ($error!="")
        {
            $error="<p>Hubo algun(os) error(es) en el formulario:".$error."</p>";
        }
        else
        {   
            if ($_POST['registro']=='1')
                {   
                    $query="SELECT * FROM usuariosfree WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['email'])."' LIMIT 1";
                        $result = mysqli_query($enlace, $query);
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
                        {
                            $error="El email ya esta registrado.";
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            $query="INSERT INTO usuariosfree(nombre,apellido,email,password,telefono,profesion,pais,ciudad,estado,zip,direccion,direccion2) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['nombre'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['apellido'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['email'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['password'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['telefono'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['profesion'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['pais'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['ciudad'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['estado'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['zip'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['direccion'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['direccion2'])."')";
                            if (!mysqli_query($enlace,$query))
                            {
                                $error="<p>No hemos podido completar el registro, por favor intentelo más tarde</p>";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Actualizar el almacenamiento del password
                                $query="UPDATE usuariosfree SET password='".md5(md5(mysqli_insert_id($enlace)).$_POST['password'])."' WHERE CodUFree=".mysqli_insert_id($enlace)." LIMIT 1";
                                mysqli_query($enlace,$query);

                                $_SESSION['CodUFree']=mysqli_insert_id($enlace);
                                if ($_POST['permanecerIniciada']=='1')
                                {
                                    setcookie("CodUFree",mysqli_insert_id($enlace),time()+60*60*24*365);
                                }
                                header("Location: mi-oficina.php");
                            }
                        }
                }
            else
            {
                //Comprobar inicio de sesion
                $query="SELECT * FROM usuariosfree WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace,$_POST['email'])."'";
                $result=mysqli_query($enlace,$query);
                $fila=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                if (isset($fila)) 
                {
                    $passwordHaseada=md5(md5($fila['CodUFree']).$_POST['password']);
                    if ($passwordHaseada==$fila['password']) 
                    {
                        $_SESSION['CodUFree']=$fila['CodUFree'];
                        if ($_POST['permanecerIniciada']=='1')  
                        {
                            setcookie("CodUFree",$fila['CodUFree'],time()+60*60*24*365);
                        }
                        header("Location: mi-oficina.php");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $error="El email y/o contraseña no están registrado/s";
                    }
                }
            }
        }   


    }

?>
```

#### HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Steller D.C.</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Bhai|Fjalla+One|Gloria+Hallelujah|Jua|Lobster|Oswald:500" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/logo.png"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="menu-login">
        <div class="container-logo">
            <img class="img-logo wow flipInX" data-wow-duration="2s" src="img/logo.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="epigrafe-login">
        <p>Emprende y haz crecer tu negocio con Steller Desarrollo Comercial.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="formulario-login ingresar">
    <h2>Ingresar</h2>
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Ingresa tus datos para entrar a la red</small>
    <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputmail" name="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu email">
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Contraseña:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password">
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="form-group form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="1" name="permanecerIniciada" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Recordarme</label>
  </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="login" value="0">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Ingresar</button>
    </form><br>
    <a href="#" class="cambiar-a-registro">¿No tienes cuenta? Registrate gratis.</a>
</div>

<div class="formulario-login registro parte2">
    <h2>¡Registrate gratis!</h2>

        <form method="post">
            <div class="primero" category="primero">
            <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputNombre">Nombre:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNombre" placeholder="Ingresa tu Nombre" name="nombre">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputApellido">Apellido:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputApellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Ingresa tu Apellido">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputEmail">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Escribe tu email" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputPassword">Contraseña:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Escribe tu contraseña" name="password">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputTel">Telefono:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTel" placeholder="+54(0000)(6564986)" name="telefono">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputProf">Profesión:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputProf" placeholder="Ej. Programador web" name="profesion">
            </div>
             </div>
             </div>

             <div class="parte2 segundo" category="segundo">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPais">País:</label>
            <select id="inputPais" name="pais" class="form-control">
                <option selected>Argentina</option>
                <option>Belice</option>
                <option>Bolivia</option>
                <option>Brasil</option>
                <option>Colombia</option>
                <option>Costa Rica</option>
                <option>Cuba</option>
                <option>Ecuador</option>
                <option>El Salvador</option>
                <option>España</option>
                <option>Guatemala</option>
                <option>Guyana</option>
                <option>Guyana Francesa</option>
                <option>Haití</option>
                <option>Honduras</option>
                <option>México</option>
                <option>Nicaragua</option>
                <option>Panamá</option>
                <option>Paraguay</option>
                <option>Puerto Rico</option>
                <option>Perú</option>
                <option>Republica Dominicana</option>
                <option>Suriname</option>
                <option>Uruguay</option>
                <option>Venezuela</option>
              </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputCity">Ciudad:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ciudad" id="inputCity">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="inputState">Estado o Provincia:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estado" id="inputCity">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <label for="inputZip">C.P:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" name="zip">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputDireccion">Dirección:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDireccion" name="direccion" placeholder="Calle Nombre 1222">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputDireccion2">Dirección 2:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDireccion2" placeholder="Calle Otra 4200" name="direccion2">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="hidden" name="registro" value="1">
              <input class="form-check-input" name="permanecerIniciada" value="1" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
                Recordarme
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>

          <input type="hidden" name="login" value="0">
          <div id="anterior" class="btn btn-info ant parte2" category="primero">Anterior</div>
          <div  id="siguiente"   class="btn btn-info sig" category="segundo">Siguiente</div>
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info registrar parte2">¡Registrarme!</button>

        </form><br>
        <div id="error">
            <?php echo $error; ?>
        </div>
         <a href="#" class="cambiar-a-login">¿Ya tienes cuenta? Inicia sesión.</a>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.sig').click(function(){

                    $('.primero[category="primero"]').addClass('parte2');
                    $('.segundo[category="segundo"]').removeClass('parte2');
                    $('.ant[category="primero"]').removeClass('parte2');
                    $('.sig').addClass('parte2');
                    $('.registrar').removeClass('parte2');


                });
        $('.ant').click(function(){

                    $('.segundo[category="segundo"]').addClass('parte2');
                    $('.primero[category="primero"]').removeClass('parte2');
                    $('.sig').removeClass('parte2');
                    $('.ant').addClass('parte2');

                });

        $('.cambiar-a-registro').click(function(){
                    $('.ingresar').addClass('parte2');
                    $('.registro').removeClass('parte2');                   
                });
        $('.cambiar-a-login').click(function(){
                    $('.registro').addClass('parte2');
                    $('.ingresar').removeClass('parte2');                   
                });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, favor edita y ordena la publicación.

"_Emprende y haz crecer tu negocio con Steller Desarrollo Comercial_" **¿es publicidad?**

Comment: Ya comprobaste que efectivamente llegue a ese else?

Answer (score 0):

Solucione el tema de registro, era un error tonto de sql, por error puse los atributos de int en lugar varchar. ahora tengo el error de que no me logea